# GSM Frequency Hopping

Tags: gsm, protocol

with System information Type 1 and Immediate Assignement, How can I find frequency of hopping channel in GSM?

So I'd like to print frequency of hopping channel

Answer (score 1):

In GSM, there's 64 different patterns along which you would have to jump through the table of channels (Mobile Allocations, MA). The Hopping Sequence Number (HSN) defines which one of these applies to your terminal device when you register in a cell.

To know the MA and HSN, you will have to decode the messages for your terminal. That's cryptographically non-trivial.